# Why does my loop stop after the first round?

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-lists

I'm trying to loop through a large string that is in the format of field:characters. I need to check if all fields are present. First I split up the string into each individual pair:

```
import re

passport_string = '''iyr:2013 hcl:#ceb3a1
hgt:151cm eyr:2030
byr:1943 ecl:grn

eyr:1988
iyr:2015 ecl:gry
hgt:153in pid:173cm
hcl:0c6261 byr:1966'''

pass_list = re.split('\n| ', passport_string)
```

pass_list comes out as:

`['iyr:2013', 'hcl:#ceb3a1', 'hgt:151cm', 'eyr:2030', 'byr:1943', 'ecl:grn', '', 'eyr:1988', 'iyr:2015', 'ecl:gry', 'hgt:153in', 'pid:173cm', 'hcl:0c6261', 'byr:1966']`

I then iterate through each pair. I want to split each at : then append to a new list. Once I reach '' in pass_list I want to append all that was before it to a final list. This is what I came up with:

```
fields = []
holder = []
for pair in pass_list:
    field = pair[:pair.find(':')]
    holder.append(field)
    if len(pair) == 0:
        fields.append(holder)
        holder = []
```

This results in:

`[['iyr', 'hcl', 'hgt', 'eyr', 'byr', 'ecl', '']]`

Why did my loop not check the second half?

Thanks in advance.

edit: I got the answer for anyone wondering:

```
passport_string = '''iyr:2013 hcl:#ceb3a1
hgt:151cm eyr:2030
byr:1943 ecl:grn

eyr:1988
iyr:2015 ecl:gry
hgt:153in pid:173cm
hcl:0c6261 byr:1966
'''
```

Had to change where the closing ''' was.

Comment: I believe there is a problem with `''` (empty string) in `pass_list`.

Comment: I actually found the answer. It loops perfectly for the second round. However, it doesn't find ' ' the second time and so that set of strings are never appended.

Comment: Please post a self answer and then when allowed accept that answer. That will show others that this question has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
passport_string = '''iyr:2013 hcl:#ceb3a1
hgt:151cm eyr:2030
byr:1943 ecl:grn

eyr:1988
iyr:2015 ecl:gry
hgt:153in pid:173cm
hcl:0c6261 byr:1966
'''
```

Change the location of the bottom '''